# Unserialize Mysqli results

Tags: php, mysqli

I am storing multiple form input value as a serialized data in MySql:

```
if(isset($_POST['bts'])):
      $id = "175";
      if(isset($_POST['bts'])){
         $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE personal SET invoice=? WHERE id_personal=?");
         $stmt->bind_param('ss', serialize($_POST), $id);        
         if($stmt->execute()):
```

HTML:

```
<form role="form" method="post" id="form">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nazov[]" id="nazov">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cena[]" id="nazov">
    <button id="save"class="btn btn-success btn-lg" name="bts">Save</button>
    <button id="saveprint" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" name="bts"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" aria-hidden="true"></span>Save and print</button>
</form>
```

With jQuery I add inputs dynamically, so with 3 extra input row an example
serialized data:

```
 a:3:{s:5:"nazov";a:3:{i:0;s:3:"123";i:1;s:3:"789";i:2;s:3:"abc";}s:4:"cena";a:3:{i:0;s:3:"456";i:1;s:6:"101112";i:2;s:3:"def";}s:3:"bts";s:0:"";}
```

or

```
Array
(
    [nazov] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
            [1] => 789
            [2] => abc
        )

    [cena] => Array
        (
            [0] => 456
            [1] => 101112
            [2] => def
        )

    [bts] => 
)
```

My question is: what's the best way to retrieve (unserialize and get) this data in a foreach function?

```
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT invoice FROM personal WHERE id_personal='175'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
$unsRow = unserialize($row['invoice']);
foreach ($unsRow as $value) {
  echo $value['nazov'];
}

Undefined index: nazov
```

The desired results is:

```
Nazov:123 Cena:456
Nazov:789 Cena:101112
Nazov:abc Cena:def
```

Comment: Have you done a `var_dump($unsRow);` to make sure it unserialized properly?

Comment: I don't believe your example. The error message says `nazov`, but the code says `$value['cena']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With current json string you can get paired values like:

```
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT invoice FROM personal WHERE id_personal='175'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
$unsRow = unserialize($row['invoice']);
// check if you have `nazov`key and `cena` key, cause you need price too
if ($unsRow['nazov'] && $unsRow['cena']) {
    foreach ($unsRow['nazov'] as $k => $v) {
        if (!empty($unsRow['cena'][$k])) {
            echo 'Nazov: ' . $v . ', cena: ' . $unsRow['cena'][$k];
        }else
            echo 'Nazov: ' . $v . ', cena: ' . "";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `isset()` to make sure they are set. Because your code blows up if `$unsRow['nazov'] = 0;`

Comment: If `$unsRow['nazov'] = 0` then if statement is false.

Comment: Hmmm, if any of the fields are empty it should be return an empty string.

Comment: So check if fields are empty. With `empty` function for example.

Comment: I modified your code a little bit, it seems to work ok.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a particularly helpful storage mechanism but this would work.

```
$unsRow = unserialize($row['invoice']);

for ( $i=0; $i<count($unsRow ); $i++) {
    echo sprintf( "Nazov:%d Cena:%d\n", 
                       $unsRow ['nazov'][$i], 
                       $unsRow ['cena'][$i] 
                );
}
```